# rvm - can't do rvm get stable, curl returns status 22

Tags: ruby, curl, rvm, ruby-2.0

Trying to upgrade to ruby 2.0.0 (and then also rails 4.0.0)

First trying to do `rvm get stable` but keep getting error code 22, i.e.

```
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   124  100   124    0     0     56      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    58
  0   124    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:-- -1610
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503

Could not download 'https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz'.
  curl returned status '22'.
```

Answer (score 1):

To get around the error I ended up doing:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s head
```

then I was able to do:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

Then

```
gem install rails --version 4.0.0
```

Comment: you didnt have to reinstall RVM completely. next time try using `rvm get head`. it always works for me.

Comment: installer does also update, the difference is get head can also do automatic rvm refresh